# I'm using a Django REST backend with React Frontend on an AWS EC2 instance, but mobile browser get requests are not working

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework

As stated in my description, I'm running a Django REST backend with React Frontend on an AWS EC2 instance, making use of Docker images, and Nginx.

When using the app on a desktop browser, everything works perfectly, but as soon as I start using a mobile browser(Tried Chrome, Safari and Firefox on multiple devices) most if my GET requests don't work:

[image: Docker logs]

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I am able to authenticate successfully from a mobile browser, and there is 1 GET request that is successful, but no luck with the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had some trailing `/` missing in my GET request's URLs. With Django sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't if you forget a `/` at the end of your URL.